# Microsoft Access Date Format

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to retrieve a stored date in a MS Access 2003 database .. it is stored in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, but when it is retrieved it comes in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`

How can I force the MS Access to return the date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`??

Comment: Where are you retrieving it and how? In a query, VBA, outside of MS Access? What do you need the date for? What is your locale?

Comment: actually I'm using C# ... but I also tried within the MS Access itself.

Comment: Where in MS Access form query, vba? What is your locale?

Comment: I'm using the query in the Access directly.

Comment: BTW all dates in MS Access are numbers eg 41073.8424652778

Comment: some dates are coming out fine, and other are not. So I want to force it to use specific format

Comment: What is you locale? When you check the table design, is there a format applied to the date field?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12508/discussion-between-remou-and-sikas)

Comment: English (US) ... And no, there are no format.

Comment: wow finally... answer on the locale... it took 3 questions on "what is your locale" before it was given... just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

Added format to the fields to force them to be dd/mm/yyyy

and in my C# application I tuned it to deal with the date in that format/ Everything is good

Comment: This is **not** a solution. In chat you have said  that some of the dates are okay and some of them are not. You have said "it gave out wrong values!! Month(Date) gave the day!!" If Month(Date) is the day, then you must look at the dates as having day where you think they have month. If you try to work with the data without understanding this, you will just run into more trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel TEXT function, which has the possibility to specify the locale.
Here is a sample of a `formatLocale` MS Access UDF.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'see https://excel.tips.net/T003299_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html
'for countries list

Dim xl As Excel.Application

Function formatLocale(dt As Variant, xlFormat As String) As Variant
    setXl
    formatLocale = xl.WorksheetFunction.Text(dt, xlFormat)
End Function

Sub test_formatLocale()
    'print this month's name in US english
    Debug.Print formatLocale(Now, "[$-409]mmmm")
End Sub

Function setXl()
    On Error Resume Next
    If xl Is Nothing Then
        'try getting
        Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    End If
    If xl Is Nothing Then
        Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In Access, dates are internally always stored without date/month distinction. It is just a real number as in many databases and languages.

How that number is converted to and presented as date is entirely up to the client program and its local or system user settings.

In case of Access itself being that client program, dates are presented and edited in the current user setting format, presumable according to the current Windows user locale. Except in VBA: then the format for input and comparison in code as well as SQL is always mm/dd/yyyy as VBA is an English(US) written language.

Comment: My locale use dd/mm/yyyy this `sSQL = "select adate from table1 where akey =15"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
Debug.Print rs!ADate` returns `dd/mm/yyy`. I reckon you are thinking of sending dates to a query, not reading dates from a table.

Comment: if you are using an SQL insert to store the data then I think SQL uses mm/dd/yyy regardless of the regional settings.  I have found that using dd-mmm-yyyy format in SQL is the simplest.

Comment: @ChrisPadgham It has always been recommended that you use year, month, day format to insert dates into Jet/ACE databases in VBA or anywhere outside of MS Access queries as this is an unambiguous format for all locales. Never use a day, month, year format

Answer (score 0):

Use the format function.

```
Format(dateVar, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

where dateVar is preferably of type DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience. No matter what you do at some stage microsoft software will get confused about european dates be it asp, .net, sql, IE or the OS itself. Mainly when there is some ambiguity eg 6/5/2012 where it could be 6th May or 5th June. I guarantee at some stage this will go wrong.

Setting the locale will lull you into a false sense of security.

So either stick with the quirky USA date format mmddyyyy or do as we do and forget about microsoft's date format altogether and make you own based on yyyymmddhhmmss in a number field. It is more flexible and more powerful as it combines with time and allows very efficient time comparison. The problem with microsoft is that they try to fix things silently I don't find this helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful when using today's date as a default value in Microsoft Access if the locale is not US. (Mine is UK).

- Make sure that the date field type is specified as Date/Time.
- Use Date() as the default value. 
  Both rules must be followed. The conversion from a Date/Time field is correctly shown with the right format for the locale.

That overcame a problem I encountered when, in haste, I defined a field as short text and later introduced a default value =Date$(). Yes, it was sloppy, produced the US mm/dd/yyyy format and had to be repaired using a date picker.